# Is it possible to set Transmission to show list of files as collapsed by default?

Tags: transmission

When downloading a torrent with a large folder hierarchy, I often find myself losing overview of the content of the torrent as Transmission shows the entire folder structure expanded under `Properties > Files`.

Most annoyingly, if one collapses the tree and closes the dialog, the tree will be expanded again if one re-access it.

I've been through `Options` (of course), but it the choice is not available.

Is it somehow possible to set Transmission to show torrent content as collapsed by default? Something I can change to 'false' in some file somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't. You must manually collapse the folders.

Comment: :(
Well, I hope somebody will later prove this answer wrong ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by clicking on folder with ctrl/cmd button pressed down.

---

I know, this question like 5 years old, but I'll probably forget this solution and google it again.